# алгоритм плавного перехода в другой цвет

Tags: алгоритм

Имеется:

- Время `T` равная 10 секундам
- Кадры в секунду `U` равная `60` кадрам в секунду
- Первый цвет (в формате rgb) `RGB1` равная `0,255,255`
- Второй цвет (в формате rgb) `RGB2` равная `0,0,255`

Как узнать какой цвет будет в следующем кадре?

Comment: Имеется ".. ", окей. А в чем состоит ваш вопрос, что вызывает затруднения?

Answer (score 1):

Всего кадров 600, вот и прикидывайте - в `i`-м кадре R будет 0, G - `255*(1-i/600.0)`, B - 255...

Ничего сложного :)

Comment: Про гамма-коррекцию не забывайте. В `i`-м кадре `uint8_t G = t * t * 255.0;`, где `t = (1.0 - (float)i / 600.0);` (или `t = 1.0 - (1.0 / 600.0) * i;` для экономии тактов).

Comment: @Arhad Тут я не большой специалист... Давайте вы напишете свой ответ, а я свой удалю?

Comment: @Arhad про гамма-коррекцию в вопросе ни слова, так что достаточно и обычной интерполяции. А то так мы сейчас и ease in/out прикрутим, и сплайны ..

Comment: может в движке уже есть интерполяция/экстаполяция?